# Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE? Может быть как-то внедрить внутрь?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть приложение Javafx, запускается там, разумеется, где есть jre. Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE? Может быть как-то внедрить внутрь?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Если вы работаете в IntellijIDEA, можете воспользоваться встроенным механизмом генерации автономных файлов

- Cоздайте артефакт:

File -> Project Structure -> Project Settinfs -> Artifacts ->  `+`  ->javaFX Application -> From module 'Your Module Name'

Справа во вкладке `JavaFX` задайте:
`Application Class:` ваш класс с точкой входа - методом `main` 
`Native Bondle:` All

Проверьте, что `Output directory` задана правильно (по умолчанию в папку `out\artifacts` вашего проекта)

- Сбилдите артефакт:

Build -> Build Artifacts -> 'Ваш артифакт' -> Build

В `out/artifacts/` появится директория с исполняемым файлом `ваш артефакт.exe` и необходимой средой исполнения.

Скопировав папку на дугой компьютер вы можете запустить проект без установленной JRE, т.к. все что нужно находится в одной папке с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: Я привел в качестве примера отдельную программу, но по моему мнению ваш ответ лучше т.к большинство сейчас используют Идею и дана инструкция. От меня плюс.

Comment: Попробовал и получил Missing JavaFX application class org.dikhim.test.Main. Не все так гладко. Я уж обрадовался

Comment: Пишет Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK

Comment: @ИмяФамилия да, потому что из Java 11 [выпилили опцию](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/90) `fx:deploy`.

Comment: @invzbl3 а как теперь делать?

Comment: @alex9127, использовать альтернативные решения, например: [Jar-From module with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739932/8370915) либо [советуют](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/90#issuecomment-477743330) создавать свой [установщик](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) или пробовать использовать [инструмент](http://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) `jpackage`, как вариант.

Answer (score 11):

Это возможно.

Есть специальные программы, которые компилируют ваш код заранее (AOT компиляция) и оборачивают его в исполняемый файл вашей ос, который вдобавок содержит портативную JRE.

Знаю одну такую, называется [Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/), правда не юзал её с приложениями javafx, но со стандартной библиотекой и swing работает нормально.

Comment: Шикарная вещь. Благодарю. С JavaFX работает замечательно, даже различные модули упаковывает отдельно, хотя и только с 8 джавой работает. И еще очень странное поведение, что нельзя собрать исполняемый файл для каждой ОС под одной ОС. Или все же можно и я глупый?

Comment: С этим я не могу помочь, сам имею 10.5 минут опыта с программой, не говоря уже о кросс компиляции.

Answer (score 11):

Часто используемый способ - это скачать [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), натравить его на свой jar-файл и получить исполняемый файл. По сути это самораспаковывающийся архив с запускалкой, JRE и оригинальным файлом внутри, но пользователю это не видно.

Более правильный способ - это использовать [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm):

Структура каталогов простейшего проекта

```
src
└───com.example
    │   module-info.java
    │
    └───com
        └───example
                App.java
```

**module-info.java**

```
module com.example { }
```

**App.java**

```
package com.example;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Команды сборки

```
javac -d build\mods\com.example src\com.example\module-info.java src\com.example\com\example\App.java

jar --create --file=build\libs\com.example.jar --main-class=com.example.App -C build\mods\com.example .

jlink --module-path build\mods --add-modules com.example --output build\app\example --launcher start=com.example/com.example.App --compress=2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages --strip-debug
```

В результате в каталоге *build\app* появится каталог приложения *example*, который содержит в себе JRE и и саму программу в готовом для распространения виде. Запуск осуществляется с помощью батника - *example\bin\start.bat*

Естественно, лучше не набирать команды руками, а поручить это сборщику - Maven или Gradle.

Comment: По поводу jlink не могу ничего сказать, а вот launch4j, как я понимаю, создает все таки просто исполняемый файл без JRE, так как пробовал и все равно возникала ошибка об отсутствии Java.

Comment: @СергейГуков там в настройках был пункт для включения JRE в дистрибутив, на сколько я помню.

Comment: Да там есть что-то похожее, но даже указав путь к jre все равно не запускалось. Но возможно просто я неправильно что-то делал

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо за полезную информацию. протестил launch4J. Там JRE видно будет пользователю, т.к. в папке должен быть сам exe файл и JRE рядом с ним. Если exe-шник попробовать запустить без JRE в директории, то будет ошибка: `"This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted."`

Answer (score 2):

### Launch4J в действии:

1) Создаете новую папку и забрасываете туда `jre` и `jar` файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Настраиваете Launch4J в `Basic` разделе важные поля `Output file` и `jar` таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) В разделе `JRE` указываете `jre`, который в папке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) И указываете в `Build Wrapper` название конфигурационным файлам (после билда можно удалить в случае необходимости):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5) **Важный момент:** чтобы в результате запустить на любом пк `exe` файл, он должен находится в одной папке с `jre` файлом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для удобства распространения можно заархивировать `jre` и `exe`.

**P.s.** это конечно не лучшее решение, но также может быть полезным.