# Свободная JVM для не свободного ПО

Tags: java, jvm, steam, openjdk

Имеется игра для андроида написанная на Java. Есть рабочий порт для винды и линукса. Понятно что нужно использовать такие вещи как Launch4j. Понятно что не сложно написать обертку для установочника и самому. Но не понятно, где взять свободную JVM, которую можно было бы без мучений совести вкрутить в установочник, и продавать все это дело, например на стиме, или гоге.
С лицензиями ХотСпота ничего не понял, не говоря уже о оракловских.

Comment: Если oracleJDC платный при коммерческом использовании, а openJDC бесплатный - то соответственно вам нужен openJDC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете свободно распространять билды OpenJDK вместе со своим коммерческим ПО.

**UPDATE:**

1. Вам не нужно ничего "вынимать" из OpenJDK. Вы можете просто указать Launch4j на необходимость включить JRE в состав результирующего файла.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. OpenJDK лицензирована под GPLv2. Ограничения будут действовать на производное ПО только в том случае, если вы собираетесь на её основе сделать LevenbergJDK

   > The copyright holders of this library **give you permission to link this**
   >   **library with independent modules to produce an executable**, regardless
   >   of the license terms of these independent modules, **and to copy and**
   >   **distribute the resulting executable under terms of your choice**,
   >   provided that you also meet, for each linked independent module, the
   >   terms and conditions of the license of that module. An independent
   >   module is a module which is not derived from or based on this library.
3. OpenJDK состоит из средств разработки и среды выполнения. Ни то, ни другое никак не ограничивают условия использования ПО скомпилированного этими средствами или запускаемого в этой среде. Вы же не думаете, что программы собранные с помощью GCC и запускаемые в Linux должны быть обязательно бесплатными, а собранные с помощью MSVC и запускаемые в Windows обязательно платными?

**P.S.** А ещё лучше вместо Launch4j [используйте родную утилиту jlink](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911147/204271).

Comment: А Вы бы не могли уточнить детали по поводу лицензии OpenJDK?
Значит ли это что я могу просто вынуть все необходимые бинарники и библиотеки из стандартного набора JVM, сунуть их в корень своего проекта, сунуть туда файлы из дериктории legal (тексты лицензий), и все?

Comment: Зачем вам что-либо вынимать из OpenJDK?

Comment: Ну вот у меня имеется jar. И я хочу положить рядом с ним все необходимое для его запуска. А это сам JVM, и базовая библиотека Java. Остальное не нужно. Могу ли я просто вынуть из OpenJDK директории необходимые элементы (включая тексты их лицензий, и все такое), положить рядом со своим джаром, и создать из этой гремучей смеси установочник?

Comment: @PeterLevenberg можете, конечно. Весь вопрос в том, насколько аккуратно вы это сделаете, а то может случится, что после некоторого времени работы у клиента ваша программа грохнется, не найдя внезапно понадобившегося класс-файла или загружаемой библиотеки.