# Maven. Встроенный JRE

Tags: java, maven

*делаю проект на Maven и использую launch4j.*

Можно ли в свою сборку встроить JRE, который будет запускать приложение для того, чтобы у конечного юзера не было необходимости вручную что-либо скачивать? Если да, то как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911049/204271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j/7582064) на английской StackOverflow посмотрите, человечество уже давно решило эту проблему. Да не очень элегантно, но решило.
Ещё можно взять [Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/), например, и собрать бинарь им, выглядеть будет как обычное windows приложение. Но он ОЧЕНЬ платный.