# a jni error has occurred .jar

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse, jar

Работаю с javaFX 11 / JDK 11,экспортирую проект в jar при запуске выскакивает окно: "a jni error has occurred please check your installation and try again", но если работать с JDK 8 и плагином e(fx)clipse то экспортированный jar-ник работает без ошибок.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего Java в рантайме не может найти JavaFX. [Описание причины](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=1370131#answers_list_answer). [Возможное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911147/204271).

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, а как правильно их подключить ?

Comment: Надо перейти по ссылкам из комментария и прочитать ответы. Если что-то останется непонятным, стоит это погуглить. А если останутся вопросы, на которые Google не даёт ответов, приходится с ними на stackoverflow.