# Запуск jar (Swing) приложения на машине клиента (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, jar

Есть задача - собрать jar file так, чтобы он запускается на машине клиента -  Windows. У меня jar file запускается (двойным кликом или через командную строку java -jar app.jar). Я так понимаю, что у клиента пути не настроены, за ненадобностью. И вот тут возникает, задача, как собрать jar чтобы его можно было запустить на клиентской машине, где стоит только JVM (по идеи она в любом случае должна быть)?

Comment: какая версия java?

Comment: нет. начиная с Vista не должна, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Придется клиенту отдельно ставить. Или же Вам делать какой-то инсталлятор jre - bat-ник или воспользоваться специализированными упаковщиками

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE? Может быть как-то внедрить внутрь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911049/204271)

Answer (score 0):

У клиента не была вообще установлена JAVA. Рекомендации клиенту: 
Добрый день! Решение проблемы с запуском jar файла. Простой варинат: Перейти по ссылке https://www.java.com/ru/, перейти по ссылке "Загрузит Java бесплатно", 
далее нажать на кнопку "Согласиться и начать бесплатную загрузку". Открыть скаченный файл после загрузки. Далее откроеться загрузочное окно Java - нажмите Install -> Finish.
Перезагрузите компьютер. Загруженая программа Java необходима для работы с приложениями написанными на Java, иногда это приложение идет в стандартном пакете Windows, а иногда нет. 
До установки Java Вы можете проверить наличие данного модуля открыв панел инструментов -> программы и компоненты и найти модуль Java Update 8, что существенно усложнить задачу, 
или не найти, что позволить реализовать "Простой вариант".
В любом случае, спасибо всем кто обратил внимание на мою задачу. Спасибо.