# Распространение Java приложения с базой данных

Tags: java, база-данных, javafx, развертывание

Следуя туториалу (https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/hibernate-java) создал приложение (только использовал mysql) и добавил javafx окошко в котором выводились бы имена всех юзеров. Создал артифакт по инструкции JetBrains (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package). Всё работает. Но возник вопрос: как быть пользователям не имеющим ни mysql server, ни jdk?

Настала пора нубских вопросов!

Comment: Использовать встраиваемые базы данных, использовать подключение к удаленной базе данных по сети, или бд вроде firebase. Также можно использовать RESTful веб-сервис в качестве источника данных. JRE можно и вместе с приложение упаковать и распространять( только те, которые допускают по лицензии подобное распространение ). Посмотрите в сторону launch4j или им подобных врапперов

Comment: JDK нужен только для компиляции программы, для запуска достаточно JRE. В составе JDK есть утилита jlink формирующая дистрибутив из вашего приложения и переносимой JRE. Прочитать об этом можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911147/204271), например.

Comment: Есть еще "экзотические" варианты с написанием инсталлятора с использованием IzPack, задачей которого будет установка всего необходимого на машину пользователя (JRE, MySQL, и т.д.). Вариант с jlink решит лишь вопрос запуска Вашего приложения, но никак не решит вопрос наличия СУБД у пользователя. Вообще, признаком хорошего отношения к пользователю, будет возможность выбора: использовать embedded-database (HSQL, SQLite и т.п.), либо вбить настройки подключения к имеющейся у него СУБД. Вариантов масса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JDK - Java Development Kit является средой разработки, предлагающей нам инструменты, необходимые для создания приложений, апплетов и других компонентов, используя язык программирования Java. Т.е. пользователю не надо устанавливать JDK.
2. Чтобы ваше программа запускался на других компьютерах у пользователя должен быть JRE. 
   JRE - Java Runtime Environment — минимальная реализация [виртуальной машины](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine), необходимая для **исполнения** Java-приложений, ***без компилятора и других средств разработки***.
3. MySQL [Система управления базами данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Даже если у пользователя будет установлена СУБД MySQL список юзеров не будет как у вас. Решение сделать ваш компьютер сервер СУБД MySQL, т.е. дать удаленный доступ к вашей программе. И подключится примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240403/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-using-java).

   3.1. ИЛИ сделать  [REST API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) и добавлять в БД данные через API. Вам нужен будет сервер в котором установлен MySQL и программа(приложения) который подключается в СУБД и обрабатывает данные.

Или просто использовать SQLite - он не требует сервера.