# Не запускается .jar сервера Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

Рассматривается конкретно сервер на версию 1.20.4

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar --nogui
```

После введения данной команды в cmd выдаёт ошибку:

```js
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка состоит в несовместимости версий JRE, но у меня стоит JRE 8u191 (1.8.0_191-b12), что подходит как раз к версии 52.0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не совпадает версия компилятора и виртуальной машины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112726/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чём проблема. Для запуска серверов выше версии 1.18 нужен JDK SE от 18.
В данном случае скачал JDK 21 и всё заработало.