# Как улучшить найденный мной способ запуска jar без jre?

Tags: java, swing

Мне нужно запустить мой `.jar` файл на компьютере, на котором не стоит jre, и я нашёл способ, как это сделать. Я делаю следующее:

1. Создаю папку с любым именем;
2. Кладу в неё мой `jar`;
3. Копирую туда же папку с `jre` (версия 1.8.0_181);
4. Создаю файл run.bat и прописываю в нём следующее:

```
jre\bin\java.exe -jar MyJar.jar
```

5. Запускаю всё это на другом компьютере, на котором не установлена jre.

И это работает! Но этот способ хоть и рабочий, но очень неприятный: размер моего jar-файла всего лишь 10 КБ, а размер jre - 180 МБ!

Я очень хотел бы уменьшить размер этой jre. Возможно ли это? Я слышал про такую программу, как `launch4j`, но я не уверен, что это то, что мне нужно. `launch4j` позволяет "вшить" `jre` и `jar` в `exe`, но я опасаюсь, что просто получу `exe` на 180 МБ.

Если что, запустить jar нужно на Windows.

Если что-то неясно, пишите в комментариях, я дополню вопрос.

**Дополнение про launch4j:**
Моя цель - не упаковка в exe, а уменьшение размера jre в случае, который описан выше. Может ли launch4j упаковать jre и jar в одно exe? А если может, то размер exe на выходе будет равен размер(jre) + размер(jar)?

**Ещё одно дополнение:**
Можно ли просто что-то удалить из jre? В jre версии 8 входит поддержка javafx, который мне для запуска точно не нужен. Можно ли удалить всё то, что отвечает за запуск javafx - приложений? И как это сделать?

Ещё вариант - удалить неиспользуемые библиотеки, которые не использую ни я, ни java-машина для технических целей. Может, это возможно?
Вот список библиотек, которые я использую:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.MenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
```

Comment: Непонятно, что не получается в lanch4j?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE? Может быть как-то внедрить внутрь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/911049/)

Comment: @Roman C Если я упакую с помощью launch4j jre(180 МБ) и jar(10 KB) в одно exe, то я получу exe на 180 МБ 10 KB или содержимое будет сжато, как в архиве?

Comment: @Зонтик Как может 10 КВ запускаться без JRE? launch4j не позволяет устанавливать размер выходного файла.

Comment: @Roman C  А если я упакую jre и jar в **одно** exe , то размер всего этого будет размер jre + размер jar? Или содержимое будет сжато, как в архиве?

Comment: Или в одно exe и jre, и jar вообще упаковать нельзя?

Comment: Java - интерпретируемый язык. Вы не сможете запустить .jar без интерпретатора. Размер интерпретатора скорее всего можно изменить с помощью других приложений, но я бы не осмелился пытаться его уменьшить т. к. произойти может всё, что угодно.

Как вариант: Забыть про яву и писать на C/C++. Там вы сразу получите .exe который будет довольно мало весить (Особенно если писать на C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Взять свежий JDK (хотя бы 17 LTS). Проанализировать (при помощи `jdeps`), какие модули использует ваша программа. По результату сгенерировать либо JRE с нужными модулями (при помощи `jlink`), либо сразу сделать запускалку с ними же (при помощи `jpackage`).
2. Использовать нативную компиляцию при помощи GraalVM Native Image.